# In Spring MVC form-tag: Escape values for XML, not for XHTML

Tags: forms, spring, xhtml, escaping

I use the Spring form taglib to generate html-forms within my xhtml page which is delivered with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8`.

By default the the taglib escapes characters for HTML and thus it escapes e.g. the german umlaut `ü` to `&uuml;` which is OK for HTML, but not for XML - it causes an unknown entity error on the client.

Of course I still want the XML characters (like `<`) to be escaped, but not perfectly valid UTF-8 characters. The taglib does have an option `escapeHTML` which I can set to false (even globally in web.xml), but then the XML-entities are not escaped anymore.

Surprisingly Google did not turn up anything useful here. It can't be that much of an uncommon problem, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the source, it helps!

The escape symbols are loaded from classpath from file `HtmlCharacterEntityReferences.properties` in package `org.springframework.web.util`.

Create a file with the same name in the same package in a classpath folder with a higher priority than the spring-web.jar and with the following content:

```
160 = #160
34 = quot
38 = amp
39 = #39
60 = lt
62 = gt
```

And you'll be good.

It still feels a little hackish... I could not find any documentation about this and if it is not a documented feature it might easily be changed in a future version. Maybe someone has a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Every XHTML document served up with `application/xhtml+xml` should have an XHTML DOCTYPE declaration.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

(or any other valid XHTML DOCTYPE.)

The DTD in the declaration includes all HTML entity names, so you can use all of HTML's named references if you want.
That said, I think it's strange that Spring escapes things like `ü`. That shouldn't be necessary if the charset is UTF-8.